# JavaScript to Auto click a button after page is loaded and delay of 5 sec

Tags: javascript

Is there any option in JavaScript to auto click a button after page is loaded and with delay of 5 sec.
Please tell me without setTimeout option...

Comment: sorry but this is the only way to achieve something like this

Comment: also why don't you try to write some code and the come here to tell us what you want?

Comment: What is the problem with the setTimeout() option ?

Comment: if you don't want the event to repeat I think setTimeout is the only thing that can help you, why you don't wat a solution with settimeout(). any problems

Comment: I mean, you could use `setInterval` and cancel it the first time the callback runs, but if you don't want `setTimeout` for some mysterious reason, I'm guessing `setInterval` is also off the table. But as this would appear to be yet another ask-and-run (***sigh***)...

Comment: [Window setTimeout() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_win_settimeout)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
var iteration = true;
var time = new Date();
var delay = 5000; // 5 secondes

while(iteration) {
    if(time.getTime() + 5000 < new Date().getTime()) {
         iteration = false;
    }
}

document.getElementByID('button').click();
```

This `while` will iterate until the delay of 5000ms will pass.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(document.getElementByID('button').click(),5000);
```

Please let me know if u have any questions.

Comment: The OP said no `setTimeout` !!